# What are tombstone files in Android /data/tombstone?

Tags: android

What exactly are the tombstone files in Android? Are they crash log files or something else?

Comment: *What is tombstone?*  Tombstone is a crash occurred in native c/c++ code of AOSP.

Comment: *Are they crash log files or something else?* The tombstone informs about-  1. Crashed process and PIDs 
2.Terminated signal and fault address 
3.CPU registers 
4.Call Stack 
5.Stack content of each call
6.Build fingerprint

Comment: So basically like a more descriptive crash report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tombstone is a file contains stack traces for all the threads in a crashing process (not just the thread that caught the signal), a full memory map, and a list of all open file descriptors.*

More about tombstones over here.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug